# wpf combobox - performance after changing binding

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, binding, combobox

I have two comboboxes. The items of both are enum values. Depending on selection in *combo***Foo** there are different items available in *combo***Bar** (binding change). The first time *comboBar* always pops up quickly - no matter wether *comboFoo* has popped up before or not. But after every selection change in *comboFoo* (after *comboBar* has popped up at least one time) *comboBar* pops up very slowly. I have not any idea how to fix it.

**Enums**

```
public enum Foo
{
    Foo1, Foo2, Foo3
}

public enum Bar
{
    Bar1, Bar2, Bar3, Bar4, Bar5, Bar6, Bar7, Bar8, Bar9, Bar10, 
    Bar11, Bar12, Bar13, Bar14, Bar15, Bar16, Bar17, Bar18,
}
```

**Mark up** for enums

```
public class EnumValuesExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly Type enumType;

    public EnumValuesExtension(Type enumType)
    {
        if (enumType == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("enumType");

        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument enumType must derive from type Enum.");

        this.enumType = enumType;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(enumType);
    }
}
```

**Converter** (usage see method below)

```
public class EnumToFilteredListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is Type))
            return null;

        var enumType = (Type)value;

        if (!enumType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Enum)))
            return null;

        Array allValues = Enum.GetValues(enumType);

        IEnumerable enumList;
        var filterList = (parameter == null) ? Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<Enum>() : (parameter as Array).Cast<Enum>();

        try
        {
            enumList = from Enum enumValue in allValues
                       where filterList.Contains(enumValue)
                       select enumValue;
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException)
        {
            enumList = allValues;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            enumList = allValues;
        }
        return enumList;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**SelectionChanged method** (code behind)

```
    private void cboFoo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBar == null)
            return;

        if (comboFoo.SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        var binding = new Binding
                          {
                              Source = typeof(Bar),
                              Converter = new EnumToFilteredListConverter()
                          };

        switch ((Foo)comboFoo.SelectedItem)
        {
            case Foo.Foo1: // Show only Bar1-Bar3
                binding.ConverterParameter = new Enum[] { Bar.Bar1, Bar.Bar2, Bar.Bar3 };
                break;
            case Foo.Foo2: // Show only Bar3-Bar5
                binding.ConverterParameter = new Enum[] { Bar.Bar3, Bar.Bar4, Bar.Bar5 };
                break;
            default: // Show all of Bar
                binding.ConverterParameter = null;
                break;
        }

        comboBar.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel>            
    <ComboBox Name="comboFoo" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={markup:EnumValues {x:Type types:Foo}}}" SelectionChanged="cboFoo_SelectionChanged" />
    <ComboBox Name="comboBar" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={markup:EnumValues {x:Type types:Bar}}}" />
    <!--<ListBox Name="comboBar" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={markup:EnumValues {x:Type types:Bar}}}" />-->
</StackPanel>
```

If I use a listbox instead of *comboBar* I have not any performance problem, so I think the problem does not belong to the converter...

PS: VS2010, .NET4.0, Debug-Build and also Release-Build tested

Comment: I've reproduced your code and see now noticable slowdown by using either the ComboBox or the ListBox.

Comment: okay, that's strange. Do you use .net4 or 4.5?

Comment: oh, i've read **no** noticable slowdown, but you've written **now** noticable slowdown... but that's strange, too... using a listbox is no problem in my project?!

Comment: @RuDAir I did mean **no** slowdown (typo on my part). I use .Net 4.5

Comment: Maybe a bug in 4.0... I will check it later at home... @work I am not allowed to install anything on my computer... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the binding problem seems to be only on Windows Vista with .NET4 - probably a bug in combobox itself. The code above is fine.

I tested it with:

- win8, .net 4.5, vs2012: no problem
- win8, .net 4.0, vs2012: no problem
- win7, .net 4.0, vs2010: no problem (on my colleague's computer)
- vista, .net 4.0, vs2010: **problem** (on another colleague's computer and on my one)

Comment: Is there a chance you're using a non-final version of .Net 4 there? There were some performance issues with the RC versions.

Comment: final version (4.0.30319.1)